# Don't read data from the input queue socket

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket

I have program code by C++ using websocket. Server side I use:
 recv(sSocket, szBufferTmp, 99990, 0) to recieve data from client
When client send data more than speed server can read, my server is block in function recv() and data still in input queue. I use recv(sSocket, szBufferTmp, 99990, MSG_PEEK) to test and see that my data still in input queue. Why recv(sSocket, szBufferTmp, 99990, 0) can't read data but recv(sSocket, szBufferTmp, 99990, MSG_PEEK) is possiable? And how I can fix it?
My error same when client send message 1,2,3. Server recieve 1,2. Client send 4->server recieve 3. 5->4,... It delayed althought data still in input queue. I can get it by using "MSG_PEEK"
This is my code:

```
Client is JavaScript:
```

```html
> var m_cWebsocket = new WebSocket("Servername"); 
> if (m_cWebsocket == null) { return false; } 
> m_cWebsocket.onopen = onWebsocketOpen(m_cWebsocket); 
> m_cWebsocket.onmessage = onWebsocketMessage; 
> m_cWebsocket.onerror = onWebsocketError; 
> m_cWebsocket.onclose = onWebsocketError; 
> I using m_cWebsocket.send(strMsg) to send data.
```

Server:

> > while (true) 
> >     { 
> >     recv(sSocket, szBufferTmp, 99990, 0);
> >     //recv(sSocket, szBufferTmp, 99990, MSG_PEEK);  //some process 
> >     }

Comment: Please show your actual code on both sides

Comment: Client is JavaScript:
 var m_cWebsocket = new WebSocket("Servername");
            if (m_cWebsocket == null) {
                return false;
            }
            m_cWebsocket.onopen = onWebsocketOpen(m_cWebsocket);
            m_cWebsocket.onmessage = onWebsocketMessage;
            m_cWebsocket.onerror = onWebsocketError;
            m_cWebsocket.onclose = onWebsocketError;
I using m_cWebsocket.send(strMsg) to send data.

Server: 
while (true)
  {
   recv(sSocket, szBufferTmp, 99990, 0);
   //recv(sSocket, szBufferTmp, 99990, MSG_PEEK);
//some process
}

Comment: please [edit] your question to include your code. Don't post it in comments

Comment: If you are blocked in `recv`, then there is no data to read.

Comment: Data still in input queue so why it was blocked in recv? And how I can fix it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Go back to making my XRP <3

Answer (score 0):

It should be the case that when send() sends data faster than recv() can read, it will block on **send()** until the server's recv() has cleared the pipe, not on recv().

Thus, if your server is blocking on recv after the client has gone too fast, then what may is likely happening is the following:

```
Client sending data too fast, but pipe not full yet. Server receiving data.
Pipe fills up. Server->recv getting data. Client->send blocking.
Server->recv gets all the data while Client->send is still blocking.
Pipe empties out. Server->recv blocks until pipe is full again.
    Client->send is still blocking, waiting for a signal to go check if the pipe is ready.
```

However, you did say that there is data still in your input queue. You didn't say where you implemented the msg_peek you mentioned, but assuming your instrumentation is implemented correctly, is it possible that your buffer, 'szBufferTmp' is full, not being purged after it's used, and you have some logic preventing it from overwriting when it's full?

More data is needed to tell if that's the case. We'd need to see your server **and** client code, and it wouldn't hurt to include the code for your socket call, getaddrinfo call, and bind/listen/accept/connect calls, just to make sure.